# Magento 2: Requested store is not found (when running from server subfolder)

Tags: magento2

I have staging server with Magento 2 installed in it's subfolder ( *xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/magento/* ) and I have enabled "Add Store Code to Urls" option. When I open my site on staging - http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/magento/, I get error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Requested store is not found

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Requested store is not found
#0 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManager.php(168): Magento\Store\Model\StoreRepository->get('')
#1 /var/www/html/magento/generated/code/Magento/Store/Model/StoreManagerInterface/Proxy.php(119): Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager->getStore('')
#2 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Resolver/Store.php(29): Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface\Proxy->getStore(NULL)
#3 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ScopeCodeResolver.php(49): Magento\Store\Model\Resolver\Store->getScope(NULL)
#4 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeCodeResolver->resolve('stores', NULL)
#5 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/DesignExceptions.php(76): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('design/theme/ua...', 'stores')
#6 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/CacheIdentifierPlugin.php(43): Magento\Framework\View\DesignExceptions->getThemeByRequest(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#7 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\CacheIdentifierPlugin->afterGetValue(Object(Magento\Framework\App\PageCache\Identifier\Interceptor), 'ec6287a9f53f52f...')
#8 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\PageCache\Identifier\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#9 /var/www/html/magento/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/PageCache/Identifier/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\PageCache\Identifier\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getValue', Array, Array)
#10 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/PageCache/Kernel.php(115): Magento\Framework\App\PageCache\Identifier\Interceptor->getValue()
#11 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(71): Magento\Framework\App\PageCache\Kernel->load()
#12 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 /var/www/html/magento/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#15 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /var/www/html/magento/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#17 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#18 /var/www/html/magento/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#19 {main}
```

So I have to manually specify store view code in URL to get the site working: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/magento/en/

If I disable "Add Store Code to Urls", everything works ok. On live server , where magento is in root of the domain, everything works in both cases (if option is disabled or enabled).

Why is it so? How to get Magento 2 working while it is in server's subfolder?

Magento 2.2.2

Answer (score 2):

To Solve this error ,you have to modify StoreManager.php (/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManager.php)

If $storeId is not defined: It retrive data from COOKIE first, otherwise return the default store code.
Arround line 154 replace with the below patch:

```
if (!isset($storeId) || '' === $storeId || $storeId === true) {
            if (null === $this->currentStoreId) {
                \Magento\Framework\Profiler::start('store.resolve');
                $this->currentStoreId = $this->storeResolver->getCurrentStoreId();
                \Magento\Framework\Profiler::stop('store.resolve');
            }
            $storeId = $this->currentStoreId;
        }
```

**TO**

```
 if(!$storeId){
            if(isset($_COOKIE['store']) && $_COOKIE['store'] !== ''){
                $storeId = $_COOKIE['store'];
            } else {
                $storeId = $this->getDefaultStoreView()->getCode();
            }           
        }
```

Comment: It's not even working.

**PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getCode() on null in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mm_dev/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManager.php:160**